# Nested for loop isn't working as expected in Flutter

Tags: arrays, loops, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Within a Stream Builder I have 2 for loops, the first for loop iterates through all the documents, within each document there is an array and each array element holds data in the format of a map, the second for loop iterates through the array elements.

I'm expecting the output to be displayed like this.

```
-------------------
| DOCUMENT 1      |
-------------------
| ARRAY ELEMENT 1 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 2 |
-------------------

-------------------
| DOCUMENT 2      |
-------------------
| ARRAY ELEMENT 3 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 4 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 5 |
-------------------
```

Whereas the output is getting displayed like this:

```
-------------------
| DOCUMENT 1      |
-------------------
| ARRAY ELEMENT 1 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 2 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 3 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 4 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 5 |
-------------------

-------------------
| DOCUMENT 2      |
-------------------
| ARRAY ELEMENT 1 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 2 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 3 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 4 |
| ARRAY ELEMENT 5 |
-------------------
```

This is how my for loop looks:

```
        final List<DocTile> docs = [];
        final List<DocListTile> docTopics = [];
    //Loop for accessing the individual documents from Firestore
        for (var doc in docSnapshot) {
          final docID = doc.id;
          final docTitle = doc.data()['docTitle'];
          final docTopic = doc.data()['docTopics'];
      //Loop for accessing the individual array elements present within each document, which holds the data in map format.
          for (var topic in docTopic) {
            docTopics.add(
              DocListTile(
                topicTitle: topic['docTopicTitle'],
                tileNavValue: topic['docTopicID'],
              ),
            );
          }
          docs.add(
            DocTile(
              topicHeaderTitle: docTitle.toString().toUpperCase(),
              topicList: docTopics,
            ),
          );
          // docTopics.clear();
        }
```

Appreciate, if anyone could help me fix this issue. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should put this line lower?

```
...
remove from here ---->       final List<DocListTile> docTopics = [];
        //Loop for accessing the individual documents from Firestore
        for (var doc in docSnapshot) { 
place it here    ---->       final List<DocListTile> docTopics = [];
...
```

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly, thank you so much @Dmitry_Kovalov :)